# How do we format MappedDateTime in lift?

Tags: scala, format, lift

I would like to format `MappedDateTime` objects just like it is done in java:

```
val sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z")
sdf.format((new Date()))
```

How is it done with `MappedDateTime` in lift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As MappedDateTime is a container for a Java `Date`, then you can just use tools of Java for dates. However, when reading the [liftweb api](http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/liftweb-2.4-M4/#net.liftweb.mapper.MappedDateTime) for `MappedDateTime`, there are the following methods which can help you:

- **def format (d: Date): String**: This method defines the string parsing semantics of this field
- **def parse (s: String): Box[Date]**: This method defines the string parsing semantics of this field.

So, you can override those methods if you want to change their behavior.